# Different MsgBox after each iteration

Tags: vbscript, count, hta, msgbox

[Ekkehard.Horner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603855/ekkehard-horner) helped me a lot with the following code (already modified by me). But now I'm looking for a way to add a counter each time the `MsgBox "message 1"` is displayed.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Sync Tool</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Sync Tool"
  ID="SyncTool"
  VERSION="1.0.0"
  BORDER="dialog"
  MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  SCROLL="no"
  SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
  CONTEXTMENU="no"
  SELECTION="no"/>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Sub Window_OnLoad
    Dim width, height
    width  = 330
    height = 310
    self.ResizeTo width, height
    self.MoveTo (screen.AvailWidth-width)/2, (screen.AvailHeight-height)/2
End Sub

Sub OnClickButtonSyncNow()
    ' Box A
    If BoxAA.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxAA"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxAB.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxAB"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxAC.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxAC"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxAD.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxAD"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxAE.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxAE"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    ' Box B
    If BoxBA.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxBA"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxBB.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxBB"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxBC.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxBC"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxBD.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxBD"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxBE.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxBE"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    Dim bF : bF = False
    Dim c1
    For Each c1 In Split("A B C D E F G H I J")
        Dim n : n = c1
        Dim b : Set b = document.getElementById(n)
        If b.Checked Then
            bF = True
        End If
    Next
    If bF Then
        MsgBox "all done"
    Else
        MsgBox "message 1"
    End If
End Sub

Sub ExitTool()
    window.close()
End Sub
</script>

<body bgcolor="firebrick">
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:normal; padding-top:0px ;padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left:0px ;border-style:solid; border-width:0px; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; padding-top:5px ;padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left:0px ;border-style:solid; border-width:0px; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-header{color:#FFFB00; font-size:22px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important;}
.tg .tg-text{color:white; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important; vertical-align:top}
.button {height:50px; width:136px; font-weight:bold; background-color:#555555; border: 2px solid #FFFB00; color:white; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; font-size:16px;}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-header">Box A</th>
    <th class="tg-header">Box B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxAA" id="A">AA</td>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxBA" id="B">BA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxAB" id="C">AB</td>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxBB" id="D">BB</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxAC" id="E">AC</td>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxBC" id="F">BC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxAD" id="G">AD</td>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxBD" id="H">BD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxAE" id="I">AE</td>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxBE" id="J">BE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" class="button" name="SyncNow" id="SyncNow" value="Sync Now" onclick="OnClickButtonSyncNow">
<input type="button" class="button" name="Exit" id="Exit" value="Exit" onclick="ExitTool">
</body>
</html>
```

The result I'm looking for is something like:

```
If bF Then
    MsgBox "all done"
    window.close()
Else
    MsgBox "message 1" 'counter + 1
ElseIf counter = 2 Then
    MsgBox "message 2" 'counter + 1
ElseIf counter = 3 Then
    MsgBox "message 3" 'counter + 1
ElseIf counter = 4 Then
    MsgBox "message 4" 'counter + 1
ElseIf counter = 5 Then
    MsgBox "message 5" 'no more counting needed because of window.close()
    window.close()
End If
```

I tried different things like `Do..Loop`, but my counter never goes beyond 1.
Really struggling to understand the basics of counting in VBScript.

Comment: When a button is clicked and all checkboxes are unchecked then it shows message 1. But what i'm trying to accomplish, is to show a new message each time the button is clicked and all checkboxes are still unchecked, and needs to stop after 5 messages. I will update my 1st post later tonight, to add the whole HTA.

Comment: Just added the complete HTA in 1st post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a global variable to preserve the count across procedure calls and an array with the messages that you access using the counter as the index. Change your code to something like this:

```
<script language="VBScript">
Dim ctr : ctr = 0
messages = Array( "message 1", _
    "message 2", _
    "message 3", _
    "message 4", _
    "aborting"
)
...
Sub OnClickButtonSyncNow
    ...
    If bF Then
        MsgBox "all done"
        window.Close
    Else
        MsgBox messages(ctr)
        If ctr >= 4 Then window.Close
        ctr = ctr + 1
    End If
End Sub
...
</script>
```

Comment: First, thank you for correcting my post, English isn't my first language :)
Second, I think I didn't explain well enough what I'm trying to accomplish, or I just don't see/understand your answer.

When a user clicks the button `SyncNow` and `bF` is `False` it shows a `MsgBox` telling the user it forgot to select a checkbox. What I'm looking for is when a user clicks the `SyncNow` button again, it has to show another message telling the user he/she still didn't select any checkboxes. And after 5 message I'm going to close the HTA, because the user is then clearly incompatible :)

Comment: I think me talking about a counter was probably misleading and incorrect perhaps.

Comment: @WatskeBart I made some minor adjustments, but AFAICS the code should already have done what you just described. If it doesn't please describe what about the result is different from what you expected. Did you want different messages for each iteration?

Comment: Yes exactly, couldn't find the proper word "iteration". Each iteration when `bF` is `False` and `window.close` after the fifth iteration.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, many many thanks. I knew I had to do something with a counter, but never thought about an array for the messages.